# Elimination of quantifiers in the strucure of polynomials and in the structure of exponentials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, quantifier-elimination

I am looking at the elimination of quantifiers.

In my notes there is the following:

$L=\{+, ' , T, 0, 1\}$
($"="$ is meant to be included in $L$)

First-order Logic: $Q_1 x_1 \dots Q_m x_m \ \ [\phi ]$ 
where $Q_1, \dots , Q_m$ are the quantifiers ($\exists , \forall$), 
$\phi$ is a boolean combination of atomic formulae ( $t_1 R t_2$ (where $t_1, t_2$ are terms, $R$ is a predicate), $R(t)$ (where $R$ is a predicate) )

The terms can be built from the elements of the language. Terms are for example: $0$, $x$, $x+y$, $x'$, $(x+y)'+x'+1+1$

A sentence without quantifiers has no variables, for example $1=0$, $1'=0$.

Reduction of sentences to sentences without quantifiers.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a structure in that we interpret $L$, for example $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$.

Elimination of quantifiers: 
For each formula $\psi$ there is a formula $\psi_0$ without quantifiers such that in the strucutre $\mathcal{A}$ the following is a tautology: $$\exists x \ \  \psi (x) \leftrightarrow \psi_0$$ i.e., $$\mathcal{A} \models \exists x \ \ \psi (x) \leftrightarrow \psi_0$$

It suffices to mention only the existential formulas since $$\neg \exists x \ \ \psi (x)\equiv \forall x \ \ \neg \psi (x) \\ \neg \forall x \ \ \psi (x)\equiv \exists  x \ \ \neg \psi (x)$$

$$L=\{+, -, ', T, 0, 1\}$$

$$\models \exists x \ \ \left (x=a \land x=b\right ) \leftrightarrow a=b \\ \exists x \ \ \left (x+y=a \land x-y=b\right ) \leftrightarrow 2y=a-b$$

A term $t$ is of the form $$t\equiv t(x)+t_0$$ that means that $t(x)$ is a term that contains $x$, that is constructed by the language $L$, and $t_0$ is constructed by the language $L$ and it doesn't contain $x$.

$$$$

---

$$$$

Let $T(x)$ be the predicate that $x$ is non-constant.

$$$$

Consider the expression $$\exists x \left (x'+x=1 \land T(x) \right ) \tag 1$$ 
Since the solution of the differential equation $x'+x=1$ is $x(t)=1-Ce^{-t}$, we can eliminate the quantifier at $(1)$ in the structure $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$, so in this case it is $$\exists x \left (x'+x=1 \land T(x) \right ) \leftrightarrow 0=0$$ but we cannot eliminate the quantifiers in the structure of polynomials, so in this case it is $$\exists x \left (x'+x=1 \land T(x) \right ) \leftrightarrow 1=0$$

Is this correct?

$$$$

Consider the expression $$\exists x \left (x'+x=t \land T(x) \right ) \tag 2$$ 
Since the solution of the differential equation $x'+x=t$ is $x(t)=Ce^{-t}+t-1$, we cannot eliminate the quantifier at $(2)$ neither in the structure of polynomials nor in the structure $\text{Exp}(\mathbb{C})$. So in both cases it is $$\exists x \left (x'+x=t \land T(x) \right ) \leftrightarrow 1=0$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) We can eliminate (alteast) some of the quantifiers in the structure of polynomials as you did (correctly).

(2) Again you eliminated quantifiers correctly (as the sentence is false in both theories).

In both cases you eliminated the quantifiers by replacing the formula by false formula so you are indeed eliminating quantifiers. If the formula in a theory is always false or always true you can eliminate quantifiers from it by the method you used above, just the description of what you did doesn't match what you really did. You are saying that the solution doesn't exist and at the same time you provide one.

Comment: Ahaa... Ok... How could we formulate the description better?

Comment: Your description of first case in (1) is ok (the part considering $EXP(\mathbb{C})$. You can add that this sentence is true in the $EXP(\mathbb{C}$, so it's equivalent (modulo $A$) to $0=0$. The false sentences (in specific structures) are equivalent (modulo $A$) to $0=1$.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: I have also an other question: $$$$ I have shown that the linear differential equation of first order $ax'(z)+bx(z)=y(z)$ has always a solution in the ring $\mathbb{C}[z, e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ besides when $a=b=0 \land y \neq 0$. $$$$ So, there is an elimination of quantifiers in this ring, right? We can write the following: 

$$\exists x \in \mathbb{C}[z, e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}] \ \ ax'(z)+bx(z)=y(z) \leftrightarrow ( a \neq 0 \lor b \neq 0 ) \lor (a=b=0 \land y=0)$$ Is this correct?

Comment: I assume that you are considering $\phi(a,b,y)$?

Comment: $\phi$ is the solution?

Comment: If so, then yes.

Comment: You want to eleminate quantifier from certain formula, write it down explicity, what are variables? $a,b$ are constants or polynomials?

Comment: Do we not want to write at the right-hand side of the relation an expression that doesn't contain $x(z)$, or not?

Comment: Yes, we do. If $a,b$ are supposed to be the elements of $Exp(\mathbb{C})$ or elements of $\mathbb{C}$. If the first one then it is correct. If the second one, can we even write that formula in language $L$?

Comment: What do you mean? I got stuck right now... Why is there a difference whether $a,b$ are elements of $Exp(\mathbb{C})$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Because we are working in $EXP(\mathbb{C})$ and our language $L$ "doesn't know" if our $a, b$ are from $\mathbb{C}$ or not because for us everything is from $EXP(\mathbb{C})$. We can distinguish them by formula $\psi(a):a'=0$. But if we want $a,b$ in our initial formula be from $\mathbb{C}$ then we have to express it somehow. We can't take $y$ from $EXP(\mathbb{C})$ and $a,b$ from $\mathbb{C}$. You wrote $a$ and $x(z),y(z)$ but for us a=$a(z)$ not necessarily a constant.

Comment: $$(\exists x ax'+bx=y)\land (a'=0) \land (b'=0) \leftrightarrow ((a \neq 0 \lor b \neq 0)\lor(a=b=0 \land y=0))\land (a'=0) \land (b'=0)$$ is correct. In your formula $a,b\in EXP(\mathbb{C})$ and that's not what you probably wanted. Equivalence written by you is correct if your theorem works for $a,b \in EXP(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: We consider that $a$ and $b$ are constants. If we are working in the ring $\mathbb{C}[z, e^{\lambda z} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ (the ring that contains the exponential sums and the polynomials, I expanded the ring of my initial post) is the formula that I wrote correct?

Comment: In your formula $a,b$ are still elements of $EXP(C)$. It doesn't matter if you write $a$ or $a(z)$, we are considering only the elements of one type.

Comment: Why are $a,b$ still elements of $\text{EXP}(\mathbb{C})$ ? I got stuck right now...

Comment: Every x,y,z,a,b denotes some elements from $EXP(\mathbb{C})$. You want to treat them as elements from substructure $\mathbb{C}$ without explicitely mark them as such elements. Basically: everything is an element of ours structure $EXP(\mathbb{C})$, it may be element of some smaller substructure if we can express it in our language and we will express that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30772/discussion-between-mary-star-and-m-stawiski).